# Call function after getting data from RxJS store in angular 11

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular 11 app that keeps various data in an RxJS store. When a component needs to access that data it calls it like this:

```
this.store.select('myStore').subscribe(t => {
  this.array1 = t.array1;
  this.array2 = t.array2;
  this.array3 = t.array3;
  this.formData = t.myForm;
});
```

The last piece of information is a stored form. It just holds a bunch of values:

```
export interface IOpportunitySearch {
  fromDate: Date,
  toDate: Date,
  selectedUserIds: number[],
  ...
  userName: string
}
```

What I want to be able to do is when the myForm data comes back from the store is set a callback that populates a form in this component.

Is there any way I can trigger populating the form once the data has been retrieved?

There is a function that makes an API call with the data that I need to run after it has loaded. The function makes an api call with the data from the store:

```
updateData(form: IOpportunitySearch){
  ...
  this.storeService.onSetAllOpportunitiesSearch(form);  //this sets the store with the user's selected properties
  this.dataService.searchOpportunities(form).subscribe(data => {
```

so when the component initially loads, including the form data from the store, I want to call this updateData method.

Comment: What's the issue here? Why can't you just do that within the `subscribe()` method?

Comment: When the data is loaded I want to make a subsequent ajax call using the data. it loads various search parameters that i want send to an api

Comment: There are several ways to do that, you should add more details to your question. You can make a call directly from within the `subscribe` callback or (better) chain you http calls using RxJS operators. [You can easily find several answers on SO about that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+chain+http+calls)

Comment: Example using `switchMap` operator: `callApiOne().pipe(switchMap(dataFromApiOne => {return callApiTwo(dataFromApiOne);})).subscribe(dataFromApiTwo => {...})`

Comment: but will that also work on a rxjs store as per the example?

Comment: I guess you mean NgRx store. The answer is yes since it uses RxJs under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to fire off a http call when you receive data from the store? In that case, do not subscribe to the store directly. Add a higher-order observable and subscribe to that. Something like the below example:

In your service.ts:

```
readonly formDataFromApi$ = this.store.select('myStore').pipe(
  switchMap((t: any) => {
    // use the t.myForm here
    return this.http.get('someapi.endpoint.com');
  })
);
```

Subscribe to the formDataFromApi$ observable in your component. So every time, your store data changes, it will fire off a new http call with the new data.

Comment: thanks but I get this error:
Argument of type '(t: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'